# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

i have a 1 issue about

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at jQuery.parseJSON (jquery.js:9011)
    at jQuery.parseJSON (jquery-migrate.js:307)
    at ajaxConvert (jquery.js:9335)
    at done (jquery.js:9789)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311)
```

where is wrong in the code, please. it showing this line : `console.log(errorThrown);`

```
function ($,mage,ionRangeSlider) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget('mage.ajaxnavigation', {
        options: {

        }, 
        _create: function () {
            this.url = $(location).attr('href'); 
            this.useAjax = this.options.useAjax;
            this.usePrice_slide = this.options.use_range_price;
            this.minPrice = $("#price-range-slider").data("from");
            this.maxPrice = $("#price-range-slider").data("to");
            this.fromPrice = $("#price-range-slider").data("from");
            this.toPrice = $("#price-range-slider").data("to");
            this.pricePrefix = this.options.pricePrefix;
            this.pricePostfix = this.options.pricePostfix;
            this.initNavigation();
        },
        initNavigation: function() { 
            if(this.usePrice_slide){
               this.addPriceSlider(); 
            } 
            var self = this;
            this.addFilterObservers();
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                self.addToolbarObservers();
            },300);
        },
        addPriceSlider: function() {
            var self = this,
                priceActive = location.search.split('price=')[1];
            if (priceActive) {
                $("#price-range-slider").data('from', this.fromPrice);
                $("#price-range-slider").data('to', this.toPrice);
            }
            $("#price-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
                type: "double",
                min: self.minPrice,
                max: self.maxPrice,
                from: self.fromPrice,
                to: self.toPrice,
                prettify_enabled: true,
                prefix: self.pricePrefix,
                postfix: self.pricePostfix,
                grid: true,
                onFinish: function(obj) {
                    self.applyToolbarElement('price', obj.from + '-' + obj.to);
                    self.fromPrice = obj.from;
                    self.toPrice = obj.to;
                }
            });
        },
        addFilterObservers: function() {
            var selectedIds, checkbox, filterItem,
                self = this;

            $("#layered-filter-block .filter-title strong").off();

            $(".123-layered-checkbox").on('change',function(){
                self.applyFilter($(this).parent().next());
                return false;
            });

            $(".123-ajax-layer-item").off();
            $(".123-ajax-layer-item").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                var checkboxWrapper = $(this).prev(),
                    checkbox = checkboxWrapper.find('input');

                self.toggleCheckbox(checkbox);
                self.applyFilter($(this));
                return false;
            });

            $(".filter-active-item-link").off();
            $(".state-item-remove").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                self.applyFilter($(this).next());
                return false;
            });


            $(".swatch-attribute-options a" ).off();
            $(".swatch-attribute-options a").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                self.applyFilter($(this));
                return false;
            });

            $(".filter-active-item-clear-all").off();
            $(".filter-active-item-clear-all").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                self.applyFilter($(this));
                return false;
            });
            // show hide filter
            $(".filter-content dt" ).off();
            $(".filter-content dt").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                self.toggleFilter($(this));
                return false;
            });
        },
        toggleCheckbox: function(el) {
            if (el.prop('checked')) {
                el.prop("checked", false);
            } else {
                el.addClass('loading');
                el.prop("checked", true);
            }
        },

        addToolbarObservers: function() {
            var self = this;
            $("#mode-list").off();
            $("#mode-list").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                self.applyToolbarElement('product_list_mode', 'list');
                return false;
            });

            $("#mode-grid").off();
            $("#mode-grid").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                self.applyToolbarElement('product_list_mode', 'grid');
                return false;
            });

            $("#sorter").off();
            $("#sorter").on("change", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                self.applyToolbarElement('product_list_order', $(this).val());
                return false;
            });

            $(".sorter-action").off();
            $(".sorter-action").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                self.applyToolbarElement('product_list_dir', $(this).attr("data-value"));
                return false;
            });


            $(".limiter-options").off();
            $(".limiter-options").on("change", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();

                self.applyToolbarElement('product_list_limit', $(this).val());
                return false;
            });

            $(".pages-items a").off();
            $(".pages-items a").on("click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                self.applyFilter($(this));
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#maincontent").offset().top
                }, 500);
                return false;
            });
        },

        applyToolbarElement: function(param, value) {
            var self = this,
                urlParams = self.urlParams(self.url),
                url = self.url.split("?")[0];

            urlParams[param] = value;
            self.ajax_init(url + '?' + $.param(urlParams));
        },

        applyFilter: function(el) {
            this.ajax_init($(el).attr('href'));
        },

        ajax_init: function(url) {
            var self = this;
            if (!this.useAjax) {
                window.location = decodeURIComponent(url);
                return false;
            }
            window.history.pushState("", "", decodeURIComponent(url));
            $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: decodeURIComponent(url),
                dataType: "json",
                data: { is_ajax: 1 },
                showLoader: true
            }) .done(function(data) {
                if (data.list) {
                    $(".main .toolbar-products").remove();
                    $(".main .products").remove();
                    $(".main .filter-active").remove();
                    if($('.ajaxscroll-enable').length){
                        $('.ajaxscroll-enable').remove();
                    }
                    $(".main .message").remove();
                    $(".category-product-actions").first().before(data.state);
                    $(".category-product-actions").first().after(data.list);
                }
                if (data.filters) {
                    $("#layered-filter-block").remove();
                    if($('.sidebar-main').length){
                        $(".sidebar-main").prepend(data.filters);
                    }else{
                        $(".column.main").prepend(data.filters);
                    }

                }
                if($('.category-product-actions').length > 1){
                    $('.category-product-actions').first().remove();
                }
                self.url = url;
                self.initNavigation();
                $(mage.apply);
                self.reInitFunction();
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
            });
        },

        urlParams: function(url) {
            var result = {};
            var searchIndex = url.indexOf("?");
            if (searchIndex == -1 ) return result;
            var sPageURL = url.substring(searchIndex +1);
            var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                result[sParameterName[0]] = sParameterName[1];
            }

            return result;
        },

        toggleFilter: function(el) {
            el.toggleClass('inactive');
            el.toggleClass('active');
            el.next().slideToggle(); 
        },

        isMobile: function() {
            if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
                 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
                 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
                 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
                 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
                 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
                 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
                 ){
                return true;
            }else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        reInitFunction: function(){
            var formKey = $("input[name*='form_key']").first().val();
            $("input[name*='form_key']").val(formKey);
            $(".123-quickview").bind("click", function() {
                var b = $(this).attr("data-quickview-url");
                b.length && reInitQuickview($, b)
            });

            $("img.lazy").unveil(25, function(){
                var self = $(this);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    self.removeClass('lazy');
                }, 0);
            });

            return;

        }
    });

    return $.mage.ajaxnavigation;
});
```

Comment: What does the ajax request return? Check this in your network tab. Is it valid JSON? `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2` often means that you expect the response from the server to be a JSON file, but the server returns you a HTML error page instead because something went wrong. And HTML obv cannot be parsed correctly by a JSON parser.

Comment: I'm guessing that the url you're requesting doesn't actually contain valid JSON data. Can you please provide us with an example response from the URL?

Comment: Yes. Every time I try to change the layout view from grid view to list view or vice versa, it does not change. I have to refresh the page then only it changes. I am getting this error message in my console. @Shilly

Comment: Like a every time I try to change the layout view from grid view to list view or vice versa, it does not change. I have to refresh the page then only it changes. I am getting this error message in my console. @Aplet123

Comment: Your error message concerns a JSON string that cannot be parsed correctly. That you change your grid view to a list view has nothing to do with parsing JSON. Please explain the parts concerning the JSON you expect, not that you also have a refresh issue (probably) due to caching.

Comment: Hi, i updated full file in my post , expect it can filter somthing, can you help to check the code again please. @Shilly

Comment: @niceonelee You are misunderstand the problem and what we are asking. We want to know what the response to the AJAX call is. You are doing a `GET` request inside the code: `$.ajax({ dataType: "json"` and here you state that the dataType of the response will be JSON. The data type of what your server is returning, is probably not JSON. hence I ask again: `what is the server returning in response to your ajax call?`. Open your website. Press F12. Go to the `network` tab. What is the status code of the response? What is the data type of the response? All things we Cannot read in your JS code.

Comment: Since either your response is not JSON, and you have to remove `dataType: 'json'` from inside `$.ajax()` or there's an issue with your server and you have to fix your server. Maybe it's just your URL that is wrong? But we cannot determine that from just the app code, only you can see Your server response.

Comment: @Shilly It showing Status:200 , Type:xhr ,Initiator: jquery.js:10254 and one message "Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom".

Comment: @Shilly  the link ajax call is_ajax , url

Comment: Aha! You have the showLoader set to true in your ajax call. And it's not in the DOM. Have you looked at the documentation of that loader and are using it correctly inside you HTML? Are you using the loader at all? The rest of your code states that you expect the response to be an object with the property list. Why do you get this loader message and not the actual json object?

Comment: @Shilly Yes, expect the response to be an object with the property list. May i know how can i fix it, i dont understand it. thank you

Comment: You would be well served to cache an not hit the DOM so often for example: `let slider = $("#price-range-slider");` then use `slider.data...` later, and you can and should chain stuff `$("#mode-grid").off();
            $("#mode-grid").on("click"` and instead have `$("#mode-grid").off("click").on("click"`